# Select count(*) taking long time on MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql

we have table in MySql DB with size approximately 35 giga bytes

I ran a simple query

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

This query taking more than 10 min then connection getting disconnected, why it's taking so long time

We don't have an primary key in our table schema, is this the reason??

If you need any other details I can provide here

Thanks

Comment: Not having a primary key should make no difference, you will still have a clustered index. I suspect the reason is your table is very large, if it is large then the count probably doesn't need to be super accurate, as such you could use - `SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';`

Comment: Can you try `select count(id) from table_name`? (replace `id` by the name of the column used as the primary key)

Comment: @GarethD thanks for your comment, I ran like you mentioned it returned with in 11 sec, what's the difference between two statements

Comment: 11 seconds sounds very slow to query the information schema - how big is your database? How many users?  Anyway, to answer your question, the table [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) contains a  rough estimate of the number of rows, this is the same figure that is used during the optimisation process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably an InnoDB table. Since InnoDB supports transactions, the table is never in a static state, parts of it can always be changing. The count() has to walk through and count every record, which is why it takes so long. Even then, it's more of an estimate, depending on the activity on the table.

A quicker way to get a close count on InnoDB tables is to look at the cardinality of a unique index (i.e. primary key on auto increment field). You can see this by running a "SHOW INDEX FROM table_name" command. The cardinality is the unique number of values in that index. For unique indexes, that's the number of records.

Answer (score -1):

In mssql, i would do

```
Select count(*) from table_name(nolock)
```

There must be a way to read uncommitted in mysql too..